# AngularJs Controller scope in tooltip form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a form in a tooltip , that is dynamically inserted. Th form on submits calls the function in person controller and  input field is mapped with scope model.
But the problem is i am using bootstrap tooltip, which creates the tooltip outside the scope of controller.

Comment: Why don't you provide some code, so people can help you in an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the Angular UI Bootstrap tooltip component?  See the Tooltip section here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.  I haven't used the tooltip component specifically, but I have used other components and was able to integrate them with my controller easily by following the provided examples.  If this doesn't answer your question, please add some code snippets to your question so we can figure out why it isn't working.